# codenameone theme.res of example todo app is huge (200mb)

Tags: codenameone

I tried building a small TodoApp with Codenameone in Netbeans (i tried to follow the example from the book and website to try out stuff) - but my theme.res file is over 200mb and my jar is also huge.

I can't really understand why it is so big. I tried to google the problem but i did not find a solution - it is a very small app and i have only one multi-image.

Thanks!

Edit: I deleted the very low and low density as well as 4k, now my jar is quite small. Can I do that automatically?

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the CSS? I'm guessing you added a couple of images and they were pretty big. You also didn't specify the density as 0, which defaulted in a multi image.

Comment: i had not activated css, only worked with the designer, so i am not sure if there is a css that i can insert here. I added only one multi-image, but i guess it was big. I did not specify the density at all, i just clicked images -> quick add multiimages

Comment: Sorry, I assumed. The source density can be picked in a separate menu item. It's pretty low by modern standards since we mostly moved to CSS and didn't update the tool as much.  You will need to pick an image of much lower resolution. I guess you picked something like a camera photo which is way too huge to draw in runtime.